# Spring AOP change object inside method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I would to know if Spring AOP can change a value inside a method

For example:

```
public void(String name){
    DTO dto = new DTO();
}
```

I would execute dto.someSetter() inside advice.

It's possible?

Comment: You can pass a dto into your method via method arguments or return it from method. In those two cases Spring AOP can modify your dto object. AFAIK modifying local variables is not possible

Comment: What both _geobreze_ and _Seon Woo Kim_ tried to suggest, but did not clearly state in a comprehensive answer, is the following: Instead of creating a dependency like `DTO` inside your method, rather create a `@Component DTOFactory`, add it `@Autowired` into your other component and then intercept calls to its `createDTO` method via AOP. That way you can influence the return value and also easily mock-test. _(I am writing a comment instead of an answer so as not to steal their reputation. One of them can write a good answer, which can then be accepted and upvoted.)_

Comment: Thanks, if you put comment as answare  I can mark it.